# Android, SharedPreferences default values not set if there is no pref

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

`String getString(String name, String defValue){...}`

This is the definition of `getString(...)` method of `SharedPreferences` so I think it's possible if I run code below, it returns 1 two times:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Timber.e(pref.getString("new", "1"));
Timber.e(pref.getString("new", "100"));
```

because at the first time its empty, so "1" will store, after that because of it has value ("1"),  it will return it's value ("1") not default value ("100")
but it returns "1" and "100" and `"new"` does not store in my pref file (located in `data/data/...`)
Am I understanding it wrong or something goes wrong in this code?

Comment: *getString* doesn't store anything. You may want to read **carefully** the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Use can only get The data  using getString.

to store data use `Editor.commit();`

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("someKey", "someVal");
        editor.commit();
```

only after that you can get this value.

```
String value = settings.getString("someKey", "someDefaultValueIfThisKeyNotUsedBefore");
```

In this example, you will recieve `"someVal"` if `commit` is used beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You must put"Something" to SharedPreferences.Editor, and commit them.

pref.getString wont store anything.

Refer to the links below:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html